# In Bash, can I output text from cut into a new command?

Tags: terminal, bash

This might be a vague title, but it's hard to explain what I'm doing in a short title.

I have a tool that removes adware and it mainly runs in bash. Some of the programs I want to kill may have multiple PIDs or output files. Here's what I have and what I want to do:

```
lsof +D /Applications/appIDontWant.app/ | cut -d " " -f 2 1>
```

So I have this which gets the PIDs for the application and I can then output using 1> to a text or something, but what if I want to output the PIDs to a

```
sudo kill
```

? Would this be another time to use | ? (I'm vaguely familiar with pipe, but not great.)

Now, I do know that I can simply put

```
sudo kill appIDontWant.app
```

but that's just not any fun.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your command results in a number of PIDs

```
sudo kill $(lsof +D /Applications/appIDontWant.app/ | cut -d " " -f 2)
```

should do the trick.